# Webcomic about humanity declining at a massive rate because of an alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, webcomics

I read this webcomic a long time ago, but couldn't finish it at the time.

It's about a world where humanity is declining at a massive rate because of an invasion by an outer force (maybe its alien but I forgot). There is this hot commander lady with an abundant chest, but several panels later she gets beheaded by one of the aliens.

I remember that the art style is really similar with *Girls of the Wild's* by Zhena, but when I checked on the artist's history, they never did any piece like I described.

Comment: Note that you don't need edit headings as we can tell from the revision history.